# Getting a folder structure relative path of a project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have a project which has 2 projects, ProjectA and ProjectB

I have a file `Program.cs` in ProjectA of SolutionA.

The following code when from from Program.cs in ProjectA:

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;  // path = C:\\SolutionA\\ProjectA\\bin\\debug
```

I just need the path as `C:\\SolutionA`.

Because in the runtime I am going to add some files from projectA to projectB.

Is there any inbuilt functions available?

Comment: If you can explain _why_ you want go from path 1 to path 2 (like "3 directories up"), you can easily code that. We can't guess what you mean. There's tons of questions about working with paths already, did you try searching?

Comment: I've edited your question to try to clarify what it appears that you are trying to do, but its still a little unclear..

Comment: In *general*, out in the wild, your code won't be running within `\bin\debug`  directory. And any relationship between files in the file system on your development machine won't necessarily be maintained when the code is *deployed*

Comment: Look at the methods of class [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) like Path.GetPathRoot, Path.GetDirectoryName. Those and string.Split should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to ensure an interaction between your projects at the runtime.

One of the exes expects that other exe is located in the certain place, f.e. in the same directory.

What you need are project dependencies and dependent project post-build script. You should copy necessary files to target directory, i.e. `"C:\\SolutionA\\ProjectA\\bin\\debug"`.